# SwiftUI Animation from @Published property changing from outside the View

Tags: animation, swiftui, swiftui-animation

SwiftUI offers `.animation()` on bindings that will animate changes in the view.  But if an `@Published` property from an `@ObserveredObject` changes 'autonomously' (e.g., from a timer), while the view will update in response to the change, there is no obvious way to get the view to animate the change.

In the example below, when `isOn` is changed from the Toggle, it animates, but when changed from the `Timer` it does not.  Interestingly, if I use a ternary conditional here rather than `if`/`else` even the toggle will not trigger animation.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if model.isOn {
                MyImage(color: .blue)
            } else {
                MyImage(color: .clear)
            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle("switch", isOn: $model.isOn.animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)))
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct MyImage: View {
    var color: Color
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
    var timer = Timer()
    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { [unowned self] _ in
            isOn.toggle()
        })
    }
}
```

How can I trigger animations when the value changes are not coming from a binding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest option is to add a `withAnimation` block inside your timer closure:

```
withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) {
  isOn.toggle()
}
```

If you don't have the ability to change the @ObservableObject closure, you could add a local variable to mirror the changes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    @State var localIsOn = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if localIsOn {
                MyImage(color: .blue)
            } else {
                MyImage(color: .clear)
            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle("switch", isOn: $model.isOn.animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)))
            Spacer()
        }.onChange(of: model.isOn) { (on) in
            withAnimation {
                localIsOn = on
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also do a similar trick with a mirrored variable inside your ObservableObject:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if model.animatedOn {
                MyImage(color: .blue)
            } else {
                MyImage(color: .clear)
            }
            Spacer()
            Toggle("switch", isOn: $model.isOn.animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)))
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
    @Published var animatedOn : Bool = false
    
    var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    var timer = Timer()
    init() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { [unowned self] _ in
                isOn.toggle()
        })
        cancellable = $isOn.sink(receiveValue: { (on) in
            withAnimation {
                self.animatedOn = on
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implicit animation for that, i.e. `.animation(_:value:)`, e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                if model.isOn {
                    MyImage(color: .blue)
                } else {
                    MyImage(color: .clear)
                }
            }
            .animation(Animation.default, value: model.isOn)

        }
    }
}
```

`withAnimation` is called explicit.

Comment: I've the same structure, except instead of ObservedObject, I've Binding value that controls the group view. I don't see any animation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: With a binding it is `$property.animation()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where to put this line assuming that model is the binding? Currently solved this `withAnimation` where the binding is changed and transitions on the views.